# How do I test that Django upgrades don't break the current database?

Tags: python, django, upgrade

What is the best way of writing a unit test in Django that tests the validity of current database information when Django is upgraded?

My unit tests create new information in the databases when they are run, but this isn't helpful for safely upgrading.

Comment: Not sure why you think you need to check that in your tests. Django's own test suite is responsible for checking that there are no regressions in new versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can always crate a dump of your database if you are afraid of losing data.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think could happen when you upgrade Django? Django updated your files not your database without permission from you. So you could upgrade your Django and run all your tests (local) to see if nothing is broken.

Comment: What if Django changes the way it stores a certain data type and can no longer read the database correctly? Is this something worth testing?

Comment: What kind of data type would that be? Django stores auth (groups, permissions, user, user-permissions) and admin log, [content-type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) and sessions. I think you should test your part of the code and let the developers of Django test there part.

Comment: For fun check out there test folder on [github](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/tests)